# How to solve Taylor series with multiple data and given point?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I' ve been asked to find the **coefficient** of $$(x-3)^6$$    Which is said to be in Taylor's expansion, in addition it is said that **c=3** which is the point for Taylor's expansion.

Also, I' have the function $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2-6x+12}$$ for which the coefficient needs to be found.

I' m now confused. I've only seen tasks with functions which need to be expanded in series via Taylor's formula (where I take multiple derivatives and then form a series based on the derivatives pattern).

Could anyone clarify how to find the coefficient? I could neither find any reference on-line for such an example...

Comment: Take a look at the Taylor expansion $\sum \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} (x-a)^n$ . Now letting $n=6$ and $a=3$. Do you see what the coefficient is?

Comment: Does this mean that I have to take the sixth derivate of the given function to get my result, and place 3 inside to get my result?

Comment: yes, this is exactly what it Means. Instead of deriving a general formula for the n'th coefficient they are asking you only for the sixth.

Comment: OOO, I see, as soon as you posted the formula I could 't belive that I missed that part.Really really tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Hint:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2-6x+12}=\frac{1}{(x-3)^2+3}=\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{(\frac{x-3}{\sqrt{3}})^2+1}$$

and use the geometric series
$$\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(-1)^nx^{2n}$$

so that $$x\rightarrow \frac{x-3}{\sqrt{3}}$$
$$\frac{1}{x^2-6x+12}=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(-1)^n\frac{(x-3)^{2n}}{3^n}$$
now let $n=3$ to get the coefficient